# pickle not saving dictionary properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Here is my code -

```
#Using pickle
#using pickle with dictionaries
import pickle
checkDeets = True
passWrong = "You have entered incorrect details, please try again"
x = input("want to enter data? - ")
if x == "yes":
    file = open("data.pickle" , "wb")

    signUpU = input("enter user - ") #Later used as sign in details
    signUpP = input("enter pass - ") # as above

    ID_in = {signUpU : signUpP} #Is meant to store the two user details
    pickle.dump(ID_in, file)
    file.close()

y = input("want to log in? ")
if y == "yes":
    file = open("data.pickle" , "rb")
    ID_out = pickle.load(file)

    while checkDeets == True:

        signInU = input("enter username - ") 
        signInP = input("enter pass - ")
        if signInU in ID_out:

            if signInP == ID_out[signInU][0]:
                print("Login accepted")
                checkDeets = False
            else:
                print("1")
                print(passWrong)
        else:
            print("2")
            print(passWrong)
```

Here is my inputs -

```
want to enter data? - yes
enter user - user123
enter pass - pass123
want to log in? no
>>> x = open("data.pickle" , "rb")
>>> x
<_io.BufferedReader name='data.pickle'>
```

this last part is where i get confused, as it seems that my dictionary data is not being saved. And this is causing my to have other errors in my log in part of my code, where the user details are not recognized.

New to pickling, sorry if there are any obvious mistakes. Using python 3

Comment: Your last example does not match your own pasted code. In the code, you have `ID_out = pickle.load(file)`. In the example, this line is missing.

Comment: what do you expect? `x` is a file handle, not the file contents of the dict.

Answer (score 2):

`open()` returns a file object, your repl output is expected. If you want to see what the data inside of it contains pass it to `pickle.load()` like so:

```
want to enter data? - yes
enter user - foo
enter pass - bar
want to log in? no
>>> import pickle
>>> pickle.load(open("data.pickle" , "rb"))
{'foo': 'bar'}
>>>
```

And you can see your data is being saved and loaded without issue. The second part of your code doesn't work because of this:

```
if signInP == ID_out[signInU][0]:
```

`ID_out[signInU]` is a string, the password, so `ID_out[signInU][0]` is the first character of that password. If the password is "bar" this line compares "bar" (the string we're checking against the stored password) to "b" (the first letter of the stored password) and obviously these are not the same string. Just drop the `[0]` and this code should do want you're going for.